# Hide h1 tag if div is empty from javascript's hide function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide an H1 title if the list is emptied.

basically i am saying. Choose from the select dropdown; if the selected value is shown hide all others. Now I also need to say if list category[h1] title is empty hide that too, otherwise display the h1 title.

http://jsfiddle.net/ajandthensome42/8Ye87/4/

If anyone could help I would be super grateful.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#selectForm").change(function(event) {
     $(".all").hide();
      $("." + this.value).fadeIn("slow");
      $(".multi").fadeIn("slow");


      var size = $(".language-list li").size();
      if(size === 0){
       $(".language-list h1").hide();
        }
       else {
       $(".language-list h1").show();
        }

       });
    });
```

Comment: HTML please. Use http://jsfiddle.net/ for code specific issue. It makes everyone's(people who are willing and trying to help you) life a lot easier and your work will be done much faster.

Comment: Put the `H1` inside the `DIV`, therefore you will only have to show/hide one thing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ajandthensome42/8Ye87/   I can hide the elements, i just also need to hide the new empty h1 titles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through all your h1 tags and show/hide based on whether the adjacent list has any visible elements. Try this:

```
$( ".language-list h1" ).each(function() {
    if ($(this).next('ul').find('li:visible').length === 0) {
        $(this).hide();   
    } else {
        $(this).show();   
    }
});
```

To put it in context, here's the complete change handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectForm").change(function(event) {
        $(".all").hide();
        $("." + this.value).fadeIn("slow");
        $(".multi").fadeIn("slow");

        $( ".language-list h1" ).each(function() {
            if ($(this).next('ul').find('li:visible').length === 0) {
                 $(this).hide();   
            } else {
                $(this).show();   
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You could make this a little more concise (though arguably less readable) with: `$(this).toggle($(this).next('ul').find('li:visible').length === 0));` (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following simple code to check the amount of list-items:

```
var size = $(".language-list li").size();

if(size === 0)
{
   ...
}
```